# How to get stored proc input parameters and values by MDA tables in Sybase ASE 15.7?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I am trying to get executed stored procedure input parameters and their values by using mda tables. I have used monProcessProcedures and monProcessSQLText but both tables are only returning proc name and not parameter names and values.

Please suggest.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just look at the Proc itself and find the information?

Answer (score 0):

The database hides the parameters from procedure calls and SQL queries in many situations. You can try the following approaches:

- if you can modify the procedure code - run the procedure using statics parameters (like 'exec proc 1,2' - not using prepareStatement/PrepareCall)
- run dbcc traceon(11202) - this would log all the ASE sql commands to the ASE errorlog - you may check if tour procedure parameters have also been logged
- add addition comment to your procedure execution code with your parameters - they may be logged in monProcessSQLText

Comment: It seems that `dbcc traceon(11202)` does not show parameters.